# Divisibility by $2020$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

The problem is to prove that given $11$ natural numbers $a_1,...,a_{11}$ then there exist $11$ numbers $b_1,...,b_{11} \in \{0,1,-1\}$, not all $0$'s, such that $2020$ divides $a_1b_1+...+a_{11}b_{11}$. I know how to prove it for $12$ numbers: by pigeonhole, since $2^{12} >4040$, there exists two sequences of $b_{i} \in \{1,-1\}$ such that $a_1b_1+...+a_{12}b_{12}$ gives the same remainder mod $4040$. Take the difference and we get that $4040$ divides $a_1c_1+...+a_{12}c_{12}$ for $c_i \in {0,2,-2}$. Divide each $c_i$ by $2$ and get the result. But how to do it for $11$ numbers? If it wasn't 2020, but any odd number less then $2048$ I could do the same with $\{0, 1/2, -1/2\}$ but it does not seem to work here.

Comment: This is not clear...why not just take $b_i=0$ for all $i$?  Also...what is the source of this problem?  Contests often feature problems using the current year.

Comment: @lulu I forgot to mention that it is impossible for all of them to be 0. I am not sure about the source.

Comment: You aren't sure where you encountered the problem?

Comment: @lulu Someone sent it to me. I am not sure where is comes from.

Comment: Anyway, take two different subsets of the $a_i$ which have the same sum $\pmod {2020}$.  Argue that we can make them disjoint. Subtract one from the other.

Comment: @lulu Thank you

Comment: The eleven natural numbers must be $\le 2020$, I guess.

Comment: @Piquito It does not matter, we only care about them mod 2020

Comment: Yes, I see that $2020$ is requires to be a factor only.and not equal to the sum.

Comment: @Piquito Anyway I posted the answer lulu gave in his comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that there are $2^{11} > 2020$ subsets of the $a_i$'s. Thus by pigeonhole, there exists two different subsets with the same sum mod $2020$. Subtracting them gives us a sum of the form $a_1b_1+...+a_{11}b_{11}$ with $b_i \in \{0,1,-1\}$ that is divisible by $2020$, as desired.